# Add alphabetical navigation to top of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, navigation, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report that displays a list of alphabetically names.  I would like to add an alphabet "map" to the top of my report that will navigate to the first record starting with the selected letter.

For example, I would like to have "A B C D E ..." listed at the top of this report and when a user clicks on the letter "B," the report would jump to the first record that starts with "B".

Is this possible?  How would I go about adding this functionality to the report?

Answer (score 0):

Use a document map with an expression that gets the first character value for the document map label. This doesn't *exactly* meet your layout requirement of being on the top of the report, but uses out of the box functionality and is easy to maintain. It also works for Excel and PDF export.

Start off with a basic dataset:

```
select 'Apple' as Fruit
union select 'Banana' 
union select 'Blueberry'
union select 'Cantaloupe'
union select 'Coconut'
union select 'Raspberry'
union select 'Watermelon';
```

Create a parent group on the first character of the string:

[image: Group on expression]

Define page break between each instance of the group:

[image: Page break on group]

Setup the document map for the parent group. Set the document map label to the first character of each value (same a group by expression):

[image: Document map definition]

Run the report and click document map links for navigation:

[image: Document map in action]

Comment: This works great when the report is rendered in IE, but the document map does not display in Firefox or Chrome.  Do you have any suggestions to get this to work for those browsers?

Comment: What version of Firefox and/or Chrome? I'm able to see the document map on FF 22.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2. You're going to see inconsistencies in presentation with non-IE browsers in SSRS 2008 R2. Workaround is to use [IE Tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE_Tab) or similar plugins for FF and Chrome. Haven't tested SSRS 2012 to see if the situation has improved.